# Chopping branches apart of a Sapling Tree Generator tree?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, unity, sapling-addon

I have used the Sapling Tree Generator to make some trees I like. I need these to next be able to animate (blow in wind) in my game dev system. To do so, I need to chop them apart at at least a few high levels. ie. So I can have a hierarchy of mesh objects in the end of say:

```
>trunk
>>branch1
>>>>branch1-a
>>>>branch1-b
>>branch2
>>>>branch2-a
>>>>branch2-b
>>branch3
>>>>branch3-a
>>>>branch3-b
```

Even just having a trunk and 3 branches would give reasonable results. Ie. I do not need to cut it down into very fine chunks. I can do this once I have converted to a mesh or as a curve before converting.

I presume it makes most sense to separate the curves somehow, but I don't know how to reasonably do this.

If I select a curve node along a branch, and click "Select Linked" I get this which is a start:

[image]

However, I would then need all the branches connected to that main branch so I can put them into a separate mesh.

Any ideas on how to usefully select each chunk of the hierarchy and break it apart so I have at least 1-3 layers of separate mesh at the end?

Is there any quick way or should I just go through and manually select all the curves I need?

Thanks